# Changing Array index 0 to 1 in java

Tags: java, arrays

Index 0 must be removed from the queue. You answer
always on the conversation found on index 0. All other calls in the queue must be "moved forward" one step so that index 1 should now get index 0 and so forth. Tried this method and many other but cant get it to work.

```
public static void answerCall() {
    for (int i = 0; i < customerList.length-1; i++) {
        if (customerList[i] != null  && customerList[i + 1] == null) {
            customerList[i] = null;
            counter--;
        } else if (customerList[i] != null && customerList[i + 1] != null) {
            customerList[i] = customerList[i + 1];
            customerList[i + 1] = null;
            counter--;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: This is why you should use collections instead of arrays.

Comment: I know but I have to use arrays...

Comment: Why all the `if` statements? Only statement inside loop should be the `customerList[i] = customerList[i + 1];` statement. Then *after* the loop you set last value to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work:

```
public static void answerCall()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < customerList.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(customerList[i+1] != null)
        {
            customerList[i] = customerList[i+1];
        }
    }
    customerList[customerList.Length] = null;
}
```

It simply iterates through the array (except for the last value),
and assigns each value the the next one.

Also i'm not entirely sure what

Answer (score 0):

You do not need counter-- and int cannot be null, it is 0 because it is a primitive type:

```
public static void answerCall() {
    for (int i = 0; i < customerList.length-1; i++) 
    {
        if (customerList[i + 1] == 0) {
            customerList[i] = 0;
        } else if (customerList[i + 1] != 0) {
            customerList[i] = customerList[i + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand your question but this may help?

```
Public static void answerCall() {
/* 
for loop iterates through list backwards moving elements forward until index 0
*/
    for (int i = 0; i < customerList.length - 1; i++) { 
        if (i != 0) {
            customerList[CustomerList.length - i] = customerList[customerList.length - (i + 1)];
        } else {
            customerList[0] = 0;
        }
   }
}
```